# OOPHP: Reference one static property in another

Tags: php, class, properties

I'm trying to do this:

```
Class foo {
    private static $foo = 'some val';
    private static $bar = self::$foo.'!';
}
```

...but apparently you can't do that:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$foo' (T_VARIABLE) in {file} on line {line}
```

Is this: a) not possible; b) a bad idea for some reason; c) better achieved by some other means?

Comment: As of 5.6 you can use some simple expressions in your declarations but it's unclear to me if your exact scenario would work (I have no access to 5.6 to test) https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only assign constant values to a class member in the class declaration!

So to solve your problem you would have to assign a value in a function or in the constructor and access it also within a function since it's private!

```
<?php

    Class foo {

        private static $foo = 'some val';
        private static $bar = null;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->init();
        }


        public static function init() {
            self::$bar = self::$foo . '!';
        }

        public static function getBar() {
            echo self::$bar;
        }
    }

    $obj = new foo();
    echo $obj->getBar();


?>
```

Output:

```
some val!
```

For further information take a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

a)It's possible see my answer/ example

b)Why should that be a bad idea? it's a normal assignment, and your making your property's private so other classes can't modify them!

c)And it's totally fine

Comment: instead of the `init()` just use the `__construct()`